# Calling reactive output for sp package

Tags: r, shiny, reactive-programming, shiny-server, r-sp

I create a polygon (`myBounds`) with the `sp` package in an `reactive()` expression.

I try to use this polygon in an `observe` function for the `over()` function from the `sp` package.

I want to know how many points there are per polygon. My `point object` comes from a `reactive` expression too and gets a little processed in my observe.

So what I have in the `observe` is only this:

```
observe ({
    #assign spatial context to allpoints
    ...

    test <- over(allPoints, myBounds())
})
```

However, this raises me this error:

> Warning: Unhandled error in observer: unable to find an inherited
>   method for function ‘over’ for signature ‘"reactive", "character"

Can the `sp` library not work with `reactive` content?!

Comment: Maybe `over(allPoints(), myBounds())`? Seems like the first argument you are passing is a `reactive` expression.

Comment: @nicola nope. In the `observe` I receive a `reactive` expression. With that I do assign the `spatial context` which creates the variable `allpoints`

Comment: Are you sure about that? The message you are receiving is pretty clear and seems that `allPoints` is a `reactive` expression and not a geometric object. I obtain the same message if I try `x<-reactive({2+2});over(x,"hello")`.

Comment: @nicola Oh dear. I used this variable twice. And once as a `reactive()` output! Couldnt see that ....